# How to use sed to delete leading digits?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file:

```
$ cat file 
1 Fred
2 Fred3
3 Fred3
4 Fred3
5 Fred3
6 Fred3
7 Fred3
8 Fred3
9 Fred3
10 Fred3
11 Fred3
12 Fred288
```

I want to delete the leading numbers, the output should be like this:

```
$ cat file 
Fred
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred288
```

How can I achieve this goal using sed?

Answer (score 9):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\+ //' file
Fred
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred3
Fred288
```

Do `sed -i 's/^[0-9]\+ //' file` to store the changes back to the file.

---

I would also recommend using `cut` for this

```
cut -d' ' -f2 file
```

Options:

> -d, --delimiter=DELIM   use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
>
> -f, --fields=LIST       select only these fields;  also print any line
>                               that contains no delimiter character, unless
>                               the -s option is specified

Comment: may I ask why the backslash behind the plus operator is needed? is it escaping the plus operator?! and also why neither of these works: `sed -E 's/^\d+//' file` , `sed -E 's/^\d\+//' file`? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This will print the second word in each line:

```
awk '{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use sed to do this

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+//g' file
```

The sed -r tells we will be using regular expersion.
We are tell sed to start from begining of line "^" and telling to look for digits "[0-9]+" in multiple form "//g" do it globally.

Comment: I was trying this and it didn't work. It's see it's because I left off the `-r` (since I know nothing about sed). Works now.