# delete numbering in a textfile using sed

Tags: linux, sed, text-files

I try to delete a numbering in a textfile using sed on my raspberry pi.

textfile:

```
0 100
1 125
2 160
3 200
4 250
5 320
6 400
7 500
8 640
9 800
10 1000
11 1250
12 1600
```

Output after sed:

```
100
125
160
200
250
320
400
500
640
800
1000
1250
1600
```

sed -i 's/^.{,2}//'   -  only removes the first 2 numbers but when you have more than 10 it won't work.

is there a way to remove the first value until a space?

Comment: Here is the related question with many answers: [delete_leading_digits][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865651/how-to-use-sed-to-delete-leading-digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes leading digits while leaving lines *without* leading digits unchanged:

```
$ sed 's/^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*//' textfile 
100
125
160
200
250
320
400
500
640
800
1000
1250
1600
```

#### How it works

In sed, substitute commands have the form `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression.  In our case, we want the replacement to be nothing so the `new` field is empty.

We want to start by matching digits at the beginning of the line: `^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}`.  The `^` means beginning-of-the-line.  `[[:digit:]]\{1,\}` matches one or more of any digit.

We also want to remove the space after the digits.  `[[:blank:]]*`  matches any combination of zero or more blanks or tabs.

In olden days, we might have used `[0-9]` to represent digits.  With modern unicode fonts, this is no longer safe.  `[:digit:]]` will match all digits in unicode fonts and only digits.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
It works only when i add a point "." after "^". now it's perfect.

Comment: @Fadri Glad it worked.  The need for the `.` indicates that the lines actually start with some character (a space?) other than a digit.

Comment: That's possible because i removed another word in front of the numbering in a earlier line of my script. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

will only print the second field.  You can achieve the same with `cut`

```
cut -d" " -f2
```